# Get the virtual url when using routing with webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, system.web.routing

How do I get the virtual url and not the webforms page name that the url is mapped to when using System.Web.Routing with webforms.

I want the url "/confirm/5" and not "Confirm.aspx".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the routed URL *for the page you are currently visiting*, use `Request.Url`, as Pavel notes.

If you need to get the routed URL for a different page (such as when creating a hyperlink to another page), use the `Page.GetRouteUrl` method.

Here's a code snippet showing the use of `Page.GetRouteUrl`. It's from my article, [URL Routing in ASP.NET 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx):

> lnkCategory.NavigateUrl = Page.GetRouteUrl("View Category", new { CategoryName = "Beverages" });

In the above snippet, "View Category" is the name of the routing rule I want to use. `CategoryName` is one of the routing parameters and I want to use the value "Beverages". The above call to `Page.GetRouteUrl` returns the string "/Categories/Beverages". (Of course, the exact string is returns depends on the routing rule "View Category" and the parameter values, but hopefully you get the idea.)

Answer (score -1):

Try the following: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath`